# radium install Error while using with react 17.0.2

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, radium

When I am trying to install radium with npm, I am getting a dependency tree error.

Command I am using:

```
 npm install --save radium
```

Here is the error stack I am getting -

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: 
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from radium@0.26.1
```

I do not wish to force downgrade my react version to 16.8.0. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

use `npm install --save radium --force`